# Не получается запустить тесты из InteliJ CE на Serenity 1.1.17

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Я уже думал, может беда в том, что это Mac OSX?
Просто шаблоны (которые шли вместе с архетипом) запускает без проблем, а мои скрипты такого же формата - нет.

Пишет

> Empty test suite.

Мне советовали поискать решение тут, но я пока так и не нашел. 
Тесты запускаю на хромдрайвере, чисто для веба.

Comment: Обнова - затупил, что не гоняется на хромдрайвере - переставил назад на дефолтный драйвер(firefox). Теперь не может реализовать метод .open для страницы в шагах

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена - нужно было откатить FF до версии 46 (или ниже) и залить в pom.xml вот это

```
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>2.53.1</version>
```

Таким образом все забегало. Только не забудьте запустить Update Maven Indices.